# Unable to properly redirect with .htaccess

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2, url-rewriting

I'm tring to redirect the following paths on our old site:

```
/apps
/apps/about
/apps/everything_else
/site
```

To a different subdomain using the following RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^site/?$ http://site.newsite.com [R=301,NC,L]
```

but nothing happens, is anything wrong with this rule? Also, how do I add the apps to the same rule?

Will the following work:

```
RewriteRule ^site/?|apps(/.)?$ http://site.newsite.com [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: The first rule works when I place it on it's own, but when I try to replace ^site/?$ with ^apps/?$ in the first rule, the rule just gets ignored?

Comment: You are not passing anything to the substitution URL, is that intentional? If so, how do you know the incoming URL had `/apps`, or `/site` or whatever?

Comment: That's intentional yes, everything under /apps/ and /site/ must redirect to site.newsite.com, as none of the pages there exist anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/(apps|site).*   [NC]
RewriteRule .*   http://site.newsite.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Maps silently:

`http://site.oldsite.com/apps` or

`http://site.oldsite.com/apps/anything` or

`http://site.oldsite.com/site` or

`http://site.oldsite.com/site/anything`

To:

`http://site.newsite.com/`

Nothing is passed to the substitution URL as the OP does not mention that requirement in the question.

Strings `apps` and `site` are assumed to be fixed.

For silent mapping, replace `[R=301,L]` with `[L]`

Comment: This is super useful, it turns out the old project was done in Zend Framework, and there's a AppsController that catches the request, before the .htaccess can do its thing...this possible, I though .htaccess overrides everything?

Comment: If there is a redirection to the AppsController somewhere, the solution would be to insert this rule-set before. These rules will do what you need if placed in the proper place, anyway. And no, it does not override everything, depends, again, on the .htaccess file location.

Comment: Got it sorted, thanks for your answer! Very clear, I'm definitely starring this!